# RxJava2 emit items in order

Tags: android, mvp, rx-java2

I'm making a exchange rate app and I have a screen with a graph that shows changes of the selected currency in the last 7 days.

Now what I wanna get is to emit items in strict order.

Here is my code:

```
public class GraphInteractorImpl implements GraphInteractor {

private final Retrofit retrofit;


@Inject
public GraphInteractorImpl(Retrofit retrofit) {
    this.retrofit = retrofit;
}

@Override
public void downloadData(GraphListener listener) {

    RestAPI api = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);

    List<String> listDates = getDates();


    for (String date : listDates) {

        Observable<List<ExchangeRate>> observable = api.getExchangeRatesForLast7days(date);


        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        listener::onSuccess,
                        listener::onFailure

                );
    }


}


private List<String> getDates() {        //returns last 7 days in a list

    List<String> listDate = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String today = simpleDateFormat.format(calendarToday.getTime());

    Calendar calendarDayBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarDayBefore.setTime(calendarDayBefore.getTime());

    int daysCounter = 0;

    while (daysCounter <= 7) {

        if (daysCounter == 0) {  // means that its present day
            listDate.add(today);
        } else {                       // subtracts 1 day after each pass
            calendarDayBefore.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            Date dateMinusOneDay = calendarDayBefore.getTime();
            String oneDayAgo = simpleDateFormat.format(dateMinusOneDay);

            listDate.add(oneDayAgo);

        }

        daysCounter++;
    }

    return listDate;

}
}
```

This code gets me the right values but they are not in order so I'm getting wrong values for specific days.

So what I have to do is execute 7 calls simultaneously, I'm guessing with zip operator but I didnt come up with a solution for this yet so any type of help would be appreciated.

API docs can be found here: http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did to solve this is I added all the 7 observables in a list and then I just called the zipIterable() on that list